# How can I determine which stored procedures use a certain table in their queries?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am doing some maintenance work for a postgres database, and one particular table has two status columns that I want to convert into one bitmask column. This database uses a lot of different stored procedures for data manipulation that are sadly not covered by unit tests.

Is there a way to tell whether this table is being used inside queries by any stored procedures? Well, aside from manually going through each procedure's body using the `\df+` switch inside `psql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't. The body of a plpgsql function is just a string that is saved and executed upon call. When you create a function only superficial syntax checks are run on it.

Sometimes this is a blessing. Other times, it's a curse.

What I do in such a case: dump the schema and search the dump with vim (or grep or the tool of your choice).

```
pg_dump $DB -p $PORT -s -f filename.pgsql
```

If all your functions reside in a particular schema (same word, different meaning!), add: `-n $SCHEMA`

Comment: You don't have to dump database/schema: pg_catalog.pg_proc has prosrc column which contains source code

Comment: @OndrejIvanic: True, but by scanning the dump, you find *all* references, including comments and other objects.